# Adding and sorting items under a specefic header with a TListView dynamically

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have the following data: http://qs.quantumsoftware.co.za/rust/items.json

What I'm trying to achieve is setting each item under it's specific header and doing all this dynamically. I did this a while back and can't remember how I did this.

So basically The Item `displayName` under the `category` with listview items and headers.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the text in the category field is also dynamic and thus I don't know the text in the category field making it hard or impossible to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I got it figured out. I needed to load all the categories into an array and then create the header and then only add a item if the header matches the category field.
Code:

```
procedure TDownloadItems.Execute;
var
  jdata, jcategories: TdJSON;
  http: TIdHTTP;
  LItem: TListViewItem;
  sCategories: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
  arrCategories: array of string;
begin
  SetLength(arrCategories, 0);
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    jdata := TdJSON.Parse(http.Get('http://qs.quantumsoftware.co.za/rust/items.json'));
    try
      sCategories := TStringList.Create;
      try
        sCategories.Sorted := True;
        sCategories.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

        for jcategories in jdata do
        begin
          sCategories.Add(jcategories['category'].AsString);
        end;

        SetLength(arrCategories, sCategories.Count);

        for I := 0 to sCategories.Count - 1 do
          arrCategories[I] := sCategories[I]

      finally
        sCategories.Free;
      end;

      Synchronize(
        procedure
        var
          acategory: string;
          jItems: TdJSON;
        begin
          frmMain.lvRustItems.BeginUpdate;
          for acategory in arrCategories do
          begin
            with frmMain.lvRustItems.Items.Add do
            begin
              Text := acategory;
              Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Header;
            end;
            for jItems in jdata do
            begin
              if jItems['category'].AsString = acategory then
              begin
                LItem := frmMain.lvRustItems.Items.Add;
                LItem.Text := jItems['displayName'].AsString;
                LItem.Data[TMultiDetailAppearanceNames.Detail1] := jItems['name'].AsString;
                LItem.Data[TMultiDetailAppearanceNames.Detail2] := 'Rarity: ' + jItems['rarity'].AsString;
                LItem.Data[TMultiDetailAppearanceNames.Detail3] := 'Stackable: ' + jItems['stackable'].AsString;
              end;
            end;
          end;
          frmMain.lvRustItems.EndUpdate;
        end);
    finally
      jdata.Free;
    end;
  finally
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Glad to see all those `try..finally`. But I'd also add one protecting `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.